# Is there a matrix $A \neq 0$ such that $A\in F^{2\times 2}$ and $A^2=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Any hints? i don't know how to disprove the statement I looked at the multiplication with parameters and looked at the different cases but there were not enough information

$F$ is a field

Comment: Solve $\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&0}$ directly, or consider an appropriate rank-1 matrix $A$.

Comment: Could you explicitely refer to the statement you want to disprove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the field $F_2$,

then consider the matrix,

$$\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: Your example does only hold in $\mathbb{F}_2$ but not in an arbitrary field $F$ as OP asked.

Comment: The question was to give a counter example to the statment. Which is exactly that.

Comment: @LudwigM where does it say for any field?

Comment: @crystal_math It seems I misunderstood the question. I thought OP wanted a counter example for an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Consider the matrix 
$$ B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} \in F^{2 \times 2}
$$ for an arbitrary field $F$.

The property of a square matrix $A$ such that $A^k = 0$ for some integer $k$ is called ["nilpotence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

$\left( \begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$ for $F=R$

Comment: doesn't it work for any $F$?